# Spring Boot get call is failling

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I just started learning Spring Boot, I am facing issue could you please help me how to fix this issue.

I have created two packages.

1. *com.pack1*
2. *com.pack2*

I have written the below code in com.pack1 and running application its working fine(http://localhost:8080/topics).

```
    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public String getAllTopics() {

        return "Test";
    }
```

If I comment the code in *com.pack1* and added the code in *com.pack2*, it's not working, getting below error.

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Apr 13 17:16:48 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Could you please let me know what is the issue?

Comment: Please specify the answer you get from the call

Comment: have You annotated class with @RestController?  And additionally You didn't defined HttpMethod, should be GET

Comment: Yes I have used that annotation

Comment: actually it might be several problems, where you app is  located ? and the packages also

Comment: Just show us the whole class for both packages.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/topics", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: com.pack1                                                                                
package com.java.practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TopicController {
 
 @RequestMapping("/topics")
 public String getAllTopics() {
  
  return "Test";
 }
}

Comment: Please  show your project structure, if there  is a mismatch between your loading class and your packages, your component woon't be loadde, and thus you ll get the message you wrote

Comment: Yes My loading class in pack1 and controller class in pack2, so what to do now?

Comment: Please move your loadind class to a  top level package containing pack1, for example the com package. your component isn't loading, so it's normal

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, you can do one of the following:

- Move your loading class to a top level package  than `pack1`
- Annotate your loadind class with this: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.pack1","com.pack2"} )`

For more  information about scanning, please refer to this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)